# How to call a JavaScript function from controller in MVC 4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am new to MVC, so please ignore my mistakes. I want to call a JavaScript function from controller, I tried myself and searched to call JavaScript function but did not find any reasonable solution. Please help
Here is my code.

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        LogisticQuote lq = new LogisticQuote();
        if (Request.QueryString["token"] != null)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(Request.QueryString["token"]);
            string values = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
            EdgeMoveService serivice = new EdgeMoveService();
            Edge.Move.Common.Status.ServiceStatus serviceStatus = serivice.GetLogisticQuote(values.Split('&')[1].Split('=')[1], String.Empty, new TenantId(values.Split('&')[0].Split('=')[1]), "", 1, 1, new SaveId(values.Split('&')[2].Split('=')[1]), out lq);
            if (serviceStatus.IsOkay)
            {
                TimeSpan difference = (DateTime.Now.Subtract(lq.CreatedTimeStamp));
                if (difference.TotalHours <= 24)
                {
                    if (!lq.IsExpire)
                    {
                        return View("QuoteDetails", lq);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "alertError('" + String.Empty + "');";
                        return View("ExpireLinkNotification", lq);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("ExpireLinkNotification", lq);
                }
            }
        }
        return View("Startup", lq);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a good practice.**

You should avoid messing up javascript in you controllers code, thats what MVC is built for. Separation of concerns.

*What you can do?*
Pass the message to be displayed in the ViewBag or ViewData.
Receive this message in the script tag at the view side (store it in a javascript variable).
Check if message is non-empty show it in alert.

View.cshtml

```
<script>
var msg='@ViewBag.Message';
if(msg && msg.length>0)
  alert(msg);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do that.

**Option #1**

Call the controller method from using jquery ajax call and then in the success method you can fire your js method.

**Option #2**

In the document.ready event of your cshtml page,  you can do like this

```
$.document.ready(function(){
   var msg = '@ViewBag.Message'
   if(msg != undefined && msg !== "")
       alert(msg);
});
```